# Remote monitoring design

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, remoting, client-server

I need to monitor several systems going thru stress testing. I want to make a client-server .NET(C#) application that will ping the systems to check temperature, memory usage etc.

The client will provide system info (cpu-mem-hdd configuration) at start then it will undergo through several benchmark/stress tests. The server will keep track of what is been executed and also will be able to detect system crashes. I pretty much have all the code for the client (have been running on the system, using WMI)

I have no experience with .NET remoting nor WCF, but I think this is a great opportunity to learn them.

What technology would you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF is meant to unify .net remoting with a handful of other Microsoft technologies.  WCF gives you a lot of flexibility to change the design of your client-server architecture simply by changing a few .net attributes.

I recommend you proceed with caution and make sure you have a good WCF reference at hand.  You will spend a lot of time spinning your wheels in the mud without one.

Comment: In my experience, WCF is a very comprehensive tool.  It's very useful to know.

Comment: I agree that WCF should be prefered if you look at Remoting and WCF. (Nitpicking: Serhio is the editor, MexDev the developer)

Comment: I think I am going to go for WCF. Any books, links for tutorials-examples-quickstarts?

Comment: I learned from "Learning WCF", but Michele Bustamante.  Good book.

Answer (score 1):

[Snmp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol), maybe based on http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/.
Nothing fancy, new and shiny, but a protocol that is meant to be used for exactly the stuff you describe. Would definitely be my first choice.

If that is not an option for you: Second choice for me would be WCF, because that can be used from different platforms (you are more flexible in the future).

Answer (score 0):

i will choose service bus.